# SQL Server query window text: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Our company has set up a new box at a client site that we access via TeamViewer11.
This is a new machine with nothing else installed. I am not aware of any faults, but the red text in "Messages" after trying to Display Estimated Execution Plan is disconcerting and as it is a client machine, can't afford to have any surprises. SQL Server 2012 Stardard. Windows 10. Can anyone shed some light on this?

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

Comment: Can you share the entire error message and repro steps

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d27f7ec7-1048-4017-8e79-5eca7ed3a9b6/sql-server-management-studio-execution-plan-error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an?forum=sqltools

Comment: That is everything. Each time I Display Estimated Execution Plan, this happens, whatever the script is i.e: "exec DropstagingTables '201701051230'", "Select 1"; everything that parses gets the message in "Messages"

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/648653/sql-server-management-studio-execution-plan-error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation

Comment: the above threads seems related.try them and update your question ,based on output

Comment: That looks like the reason. I'll forward this to our IT chaps.